# How to disable (or remap) the Office Hot-key

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-11, powertoys

How can I deactivate (or remap) the "Office key"? See (2) in this image:

[image]

I have tried to use "Keyboard Mapper" from Power-Toys, but the problem is, that I don't know which key to select.
i.e. when I click on "Type" and then press the "Office key" it reports "Win (left)" which is not okay, because this is the same as (1). And I want the Windows key (1) to work, but not (2).
Maybe I must select another item from the keys dropdown-list? e.g. "VK 150", etc.

Thanks to the comment from @Destroy666 I found out, that the store key uses the same key-code (91) but with shift+alt+ctrl enabled.
So I tried "Remap shortcuts" in Power-Toys, but his does not work:
[image]

When I click OK to close the dialogue, I get "Some of the shortcuts could not be remapped" and when I continue, the mapping is gone.

Or do you know any other way or tool to deactivate this key?

Comment: What's the keycode that's reported here? https://www.toptal.com/developers/keycode Edit your question with the "event dump" part.

Comment: @Destroy666 thanks, that's helpful. I can see that both provide the same Event Dump, except that for the Store Key, alt, ctrl and shift are true (for the left-win key those are false)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to the helpful comment from @Destroy666 I found an easy way to deactivate this key

- open a CMD window (maybe as admin - but for me it worked in a normal CMD)
- and execute:

  ```
  REG ADD HKCU\Software\Classes\ms-officeapp\Shell\Open\Command /t REG_SZ /d rundll32
  ```

To undo the operation, delete the key

```
REG DELETE HKCU\Software\Classes\ms-officeapp\Shell\Open\Command
```

[Disabling the Office hotkey in Windows 10](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/disabling-the-office-hotkey-in-windows-10/58e2f30f-8556-4f73-bf0c-56544697218d)

> The default mapping of Alt+Shift+Ctrl+Win is to open Office applications. Currently, you can disable this feature by changing the registry to turn off the shortcut key for opening Office applications. Pressing Alt+Shift+Ctrl+Win will no longer open the Office application.
>
> However, if you want to use the "Hyper" key to set other shortcuts, you need to follow this rule and change it through the registry. Modifying the registry has risks. Perform this operation with caution.
>
> I will list the contents of the registry for closing Office application shortcuts below.
>
> Click Search on the taskbar, enter CMD, select Run as administrator to open, enter the following command and press Enter:
>
> `REG ADD HKCU\Software\Classes\ms-officeapp\Shell\Open\Command /t REG_SZ /d rundll32`
> After this command is completed, the Office app shortcut will be disabled and the Hyper key will not open it again.
>
> Disclaimer: Generally, modifying registry subkeys or work group is intended for advanced users, administrators, and IT Professionals. It can help fix some problems, however, serious problems might occur if you modify the registry incorrectly. Therefore, make sure that you follow these steps carefully. For further protection, back up the registry before you modify it. Then, you can restore the registry if a problem occurs. For more information about how to back up and restore the registry, click here to view the article.

Answer (score 2):

You can always check key codes and some of the modifiers with a tool like [this](https://www.toptal.com/developers/keycode).

If your report about it being <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Win</kbd> is correct, you can disable this combination with [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) this way:

```
+!^LWin::
Send {Blind}{vkE8}
Return
```

The [{Blind}](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Send.htm#Blind) part is needed to avoid the <kbd>Win</kbd> key press execution.

Depending on the order in which the "Office" key "presses" these, blocking a proper order may be needed, since they're all modifier keys. Here are all of them:

```
+!^LWin::
#^!Shift::
#^+Alt::
#!+Ctrl::
Send {Blind}{vkE8}
Return
```

You could just use the above to be safe or find out the proper combo.